# Buscando nomes específicos dentro de linhas

Tags: r

Tenho um banco de dados sobre partidos e em uma linha tenho uma série de sigla do tipo: `PT/PSDC/PCB/PMDB`. Como faço para selecionar apenas o `PMDB` dentro dessas linhas?

Comment: Você precisa postar uma amostra do seu banco de dados, para podermos entender com qual tipo de dados estamos lidando, sem essa informação não há como fazer nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso:

```
partido<-c('PT/PSDC/PCB/PMDB')

library(stringr)
str_extract(partido,'PMDB')
```

Esta função extrai o primeiro elemento encontrado (no caso, apenas uma unidade de `PMDB`). Se há vários `PMDB`s dentro do vetor, use `str_extract_all` para extrair todas as siglas `PMDB`:

```
str_extract_all(partido,'PMDB')
```